# Write dynamically base on the row number using python csv spamwriter

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write csv files. Currently I have 100 different files, each one has different column number. Traditionally I have to write 100 * m[n] if the file has 100 columns. Is there a way I could just specify n # of columns and it will write out a file with n columns? In other words, make [m[1], m[2]....m[n] dynamic.

```
with open(outdir, 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for m in df:
        spamwriter.writerow([m[1], m[2]....m[n]])
```

Comment: what about `m[1:n+1]` (note indices start at 1 probably `m[:n]` is what you need

Comment: Yes, but you still have to put a comma to separate each field. if use m[1:n+1], there is no way to put a comma in between, then you have to write '|' in the string and manually split it.

Comment: the comma is managed by `csv.writer`